# Rails - access node_modules in application.js with browserify rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, browserify-rails

The [browserify-rails documentation](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) says "By default only files in /app and /node_modules are browserified". However, when I install a package from npmjs and try to reference it in `application.js`, the app cannot find it. Is there a way to require node_modules in my Rails app using browserify-rails?

```
# command line
$ npm intl-tel-input --save

# application.js.coffee
#= require intlTelInput

# throws error
Error: Cannot find module 'intlTelInput' from '.../app/assets/javascripts'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `#= require ...` then it still uses Rails asset pipeline and that will not be able to access the npm modules. What you should do instead is to use

```
var intlTelInput = require("intlTelInput");
```

which browserify will parse and find from the npm modules. If you have included an ES6 parser (like babelify) then you could even do it like this

```
import intlTelInput from "intlTelInput"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This gets me a step closer as it seems to load the file but it doesn't seem add it as a jQuery extension: `$(...).intlTelInput  is not a function` Sounds like maybe I need to handle that in some other way?

Comment: If you want to use jQuery in your browserify module,s then it needs to be required in the same way. Make sure you have jQuery added as a dependency in `package.json` and then you can require it where you need it be adding `var $ = require('jQuery');`